# How to match float value in mongoquery?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

This is my sample documents collection of MongoDB. I need an expected result so anyone guide me to solve my problem

```
/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : 1.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125001",
  "tu_code" : "5"
}
/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : 2.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125002",
  "tu_code" : "50"
}
/* 3 */
{
  "_id" : 3.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125003",
  "tu_code" : "50.21"
}
/* 4 */
{
  "_id" : 4.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125004",
  "tu_code" : "50.22"
}
/* 5 */
{
  "_id" : 5.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125005",
  "tu_code" : "52"
}
/* 6 */
{
  "_id" : 3.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125006",
  "tu_code" : "5.1"
}
/* 7 */
{
  "_id" : 6.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125007",
  "tu_code" : "5.1.1"
}
/* 8 */
{
  "_id" : 7.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125008",
  "tu_code" : "5.2"
}
/* 9 */
{
  "_id" : 8.0,
  "user_id" : "5c592f6716209a24f4125009",
  "tu_code" : "5.2.1"
}
```

Here I mentioned my mongo **aggregate** query below

```
[ 
    { "$project": { 
        "tu_code": { "$toLower": "$tu_code" }, 
    }}, 
    { "$match": { "tu_code": {"$regex": "^5.*"}}}
]
```

This above query produces the below result

```
    | _id| tu_code |

    | ---| --------|

    | 1  | 5     |
    | 2  | 50    |
    | 3  | 50.21 |
    | 4  | 50.22 |
    | 5  | 52    |
    | 6  | 53    |
    | 7  | 5.1   |
    | 8  | 5.1.1 |
    | 9  | 5.2   |
    | 10 | 5.2.1 |
```

But I want **expected result** given below

```
    | _id| tu_code |

    | ---| --------|

    | 1  | 5     |
    | 7  | 5.1   |
    | 8  | 5.1.1 |
    | 9  | 5.2   |
    | 10 | 5.2.1 |
```

Anyone help me to solve this I don't know how to get my expected result.

Comment: please post some example documents and explain your expected result.

Comment: @turivishal I matched the tu_code of 5 and I want to get 5 and 5. values only but I get 50,51 unwanted values so I expected my value start with 5,5.1,5.1.1 like wise

Comment: @turivishal I posted sample documents so please verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the `\b` (word boundary) operator at the end of search expression,

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "tu_code": {
        "$regex": "^5\\b"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E0P2fUDPfXj)